# Relativic magnetic field(?)

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, magnetic-fields, inertial-frames

So, I have a question since my fundamental school that a can't find an answer even today, I'm sad about that..

Here it goes,
Imagine I have a charge on my hands, for a observer i'm sitting and that charge is not moving.
Now, I'm still with that charge, but I'm in a car. For an observer, that charge is moving, so it produces a magnetic field, but for me the charge is not moving at all, the car is on constant speed.

Einstein said the physics laws must be the same at any inertial reference, how it works for this problem that I mentioned?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moving charge in different frames of reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/518789/)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually the very issue that motivated Einstein to write his paper on Special Relativity.  Electric fields become magnetic fields, and vise versa, when you change your frame of reference (state of motion).  In the car, you do not observe a magnetic field, but the outside observers do.  And they observe differences in the electric field compared to what you observe.  But any actual observable fact, like the deflection of a compass needle near your charge, will be identical in both frames. But the reason people give for it may be different